# Postman sending raw data

Tags: json, laravel, postman, raw-data

Im trying to send raw data to a web service I have. The service is waiting for a object named viaje which has the next data:
* idDestino a numeric id
* idLanta a numeric id
* idPeticion an array of numeric ids
* idVehiculo a numeric id

Heres is what im trying out, but it wont even detect the index viaje.

```
{
  "viaje" : 
    [{
      "idDestino" : 7,
      "idLlanta" : 7,
      "idPeticiones" : [{2,12]],
      "idVehiculo" : 1,
    }]
}
```

Im using laravel for the web services and here is how Im reciving the data.

```
$object = Input::all(); 

$object = $object["viaje"];

//VARIABLES DE LOGIN INPUTS
$idDestino = $object['idDestino'];
$fechaInicio = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$idLlanta = $object['idLlanta'];
$idPeticiones = $object['idPeticiones'];
$idVehiculo = $object['idVehiculo'];
```

what I want to know is how do I structure the raw data Im sending to fit the description I just gave. Also if doing this in form-data is possible how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out how to do the format for the json array:

```
{ 
  "viaje" : { 
    "idPeticiones": [ 
      "1",
      "12" 
    ], 
    "idLlanta": 4,
    "idDestino": 7, 
    "idVehiculo": 1
  }
}
```

I was using {} an object instead of {} an array